# How to store files to AWS S3 using java AWS lambda?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

How to store files to AWS S3 using java AWS lambda?I have created S3 bucket and IAM user and Given permission to the user "S3AccessPermision".

Comment: Are you asking for a method to upload files? Have you read the AWS SDK for Java documentation? For example: [Performing Operations on Amazon S3 Objects - AWS SDK for Java](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-s3-objects.html)

Comment: Yes I want method to upload files.I tried with some of the methods,still I am not getting as I am new to AWS Lambda..Please provide me links for  reference.

Answer (score 0):

To store files to your S3 bucket follow the below steps:

- Open the bucket in which you want to store the files, click on the
  properties and edit the policy and permissions. This will allow the
  user to read and write to the bucket.

**Bucket Policy**:

```
{
 “Sid”: “PublicReadGetObject”,
 “Effect”: “Allow”,
 “Principal”: “*”,
 “Action”: “s3:GetObject”,
 “Resource”: “arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/*”
 }
```

- Allow Lambda to Assume an IAM Role:
- Go to IAM Console, in the Navigation Pane ,choose **Roles** and then
  choose Create Role  For **Select type of trusted entity**, choose **AWS
  service**, and then choose **Lambda** for the service that will use this
  role. Then choose Next: **Permissions**.
- For **Attach permissions policy**, choose **AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole**.
  This allows Lambda to write to your CloudWatch Logs resources. Then
  choose Next: Review.
- Add a name for your role and a description for the role. Then choose
  **Create role** to finish creating the IAM role.
- Go to your Lambda Console and create a function. In the **Permissions**
  Section → **Choose or create an existing role**, attach the Role created
  in the IAM console that has the basic lambda execution permissions.
- Upload the java code to your lambda function and Click on **'Test'**
  button to invoke the lambda function. After executing the function,
  you can check that output file has been created in the S3 bucket
  specified in the code.

Comment: The S3 bucket policy seems unneeded here.